# How to resolve ModbusSlaveException: Error Code = 3?

Tags: java, modbus, sourceforge

I am having a modbus project where i am getting error code 3 while reading from device. If anyone knows what is the problem and how to resolve please help out.

```
net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusSlaveException: Error Code = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Exception code 3 is "Illegal value", and it means that one of the values you provided in the request is illegal.  This won't be an invalid address as that is exception code 2 ("Illegal address").  Which means that most likely your count of registers to read is either less than or equal to 0 or greater than the maximum number of registers which may be read per request -- typically 125 or so.